# Wow.js and Animate.css not working for full web page by setting fixed image background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I am trying to set fixed image background in my web page.I had some issues with fixed image background,it was not displaying properly in mobile phone browsers.I went through these links:

[CSS - Background images not displaying properly on mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191089/css-background-images-not-displaying-properly-on-mobile-browsers)

[Fixed body background scrolls with the page on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045364/fixed-body-background-scrolls-with-the-page-on-ios7)

finally I found solution for that from http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sGvxe

here is my code:

```
html {
background: url("../img/bg.jpg") #F0F0F0 no-repeat center center       fixed;
background-size: 100% 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
}

body {
background-color: transparent !
height: 100% !important;
margin: 0px !important;
overflow: auto !important;
}
```

This code works fine to display fixed image background for most of the browsers including mobile browsers but the problem is with wow.js and animate.css libraries, these are not giving effects on whole page.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

or any alternate way to set fixed image background which should work properly in all devices including mobile phone browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show us a codepen with your problem? Tried to simulate it here, but didn't get your error when trying to animate something in your screen.