# Fixed background images in Safari - Not aligning to bottom of viewport

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I am noticing in Safari, fixed cover backgrounds don't justify properly. Using `background-position: left bottom;` , the background image should be justified to the bottom left corner of it's container, so for example image given the logo should always be present since it's in said corner.

See the example below, in Firefox the logo on the bottom left of image appears, and on Safari (Version 8.0.3) it doesn't.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: left bottom;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/b6hszasz/1/

Behavior: Firefox Left / Safari Right

[image]

Comment: Since you're using a fixed background attachment, the bottom logo will of course not be visible all times, but in a certain scroll position range. I don't see how your example fails to work in Safari. Also, what do you mean by "don't justify properly"? You have to be explicit about your issue (and the desired behaviour)—we do not know what you consider as proper or not.

Comment: I added some more detail for you. Yes it's fixed, however background-position: left bottom; should control where it's fixed to, and in the example given should always show the bottom left corner of the image.

Comment: I still have no issues seeing the logo. Using Safari 9.

Comment: I have confirmed this is happening across multiple installations of Safari, and on my local computer I can replicate it with Safari 8. Cannot see logo: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAiugGGmm2lGWK-XyasJ1-NpJLSCxC1Fjcw

Comment: I checked in Safari 8 and I'm not seeing the issue either. It almost sounds like you want the background image fixed but the foreground logo positioned absolutely in the bottom left.  If that's the case, could you separate the two and position/attach them separately?

Comment: Here are a couple of similar SO questions that may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045364/fixed-body-background-scrolls-with-the-page-on-ios7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot the problem seems to be a `iframe` scrolling problem. I can reproduce your issue not only on `Safari`, but on `Firefox` and `Chrome` as well.

In the embedded view of `jsfiddle`, the "result" iframe is in a div with `padding-top`. But the `iframe` height is calculated without the `padding`, so it becomes possible to `scroll` in the frame. Your `fixed background` stays at the `bottom` of its own `window`, but this window scrolls, so at some points it gets lower that bottom of the browser. You can test it by opening your link:

http://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/b6hszasz/1/embedded/result/

Then opening the console and run this line:

```
document.getElementById('result').style.padding = '0px'
```

You should see your `background` behaving normally. Since iframes in `jsfiddle` are sandboxed, not sure there's a way from your `iframe` to correct this.

Note that this is based on your screenshot, your fiddle and on the behaviors on my browsers, there may be another issue as well. But on my end I can reproduce this problem fairly easily.

EDIT:

Looking at your live site, it's pretty clear there's another issue, which clearly looks like a bug. What seems to happen is that Safari considers the `viewport` as being the `outerHeight` of the window instead of `innerHeight`. I'm guessing it's because of the transparency effect in the toolbar/header. In any case, you can see this clearly running a few commands in console. This one doesn't move the image at all, which suggest that the `100% position y` is made according to `outerHeight` instead of `innerHeight`:

```
$('.image').css("background-position", "left -" + ($('.image').width() - window.outerHeight) + "px")
```

But when using this one moves it properly:

```
$('.image').css("background-position", "left -" + ($('.image').width() - window.innerHeight) + "px")
```

So I guess one solution would be to detect Safari and define dynamically background position this way. But then you would have to redefine on resize as well.

Comment: This is not related to an iframe, it's happening also on my real site (http://ericdoak.pairserver.com/why-renew) where there is no iframe. Constantly I can reproduce in Safari only, the background image does not get fixed to bottom left and the logo gets cut off.