# Change Background-Attachment from fixed to scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, fixed

Is there a way to change the property of my bg-attachments from fixed to scroll.
I am making a website with parallax scroll, which doesn't work on iOS.

I found something with Javascript which detects the operating system([link Javascript example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045364/fixed-body-background-scrolls-with-the-page-on-ios7)), but can it be that simple?

Thanks for any help!

Jakob

[image javascript example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsaBU.png)