# Why is my mobile background different on my iphone than in devtools?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

So I used Chrome Dev tools to check the responsiveness on an iphone and it looks fine. But when I check out the site on my actual iphone the background is completely different. Here is the link to my code https://github.com/CurtisKil/manesseGrading_2

[How it looks on Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIr3x.jpg)

[How it actually looks on iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku6ZW.jpg)

Comment: Hi @CurtisK. The issue is coming from `background-attachment: fixed;`. Please have a look at my answer to understand how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is:

`background-attachment: fixed;` does not work well with most browsers and especially does not work properly on iOS. (Read more here on why: [How to replicate background-attachment fixed on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios))

**Quick Fix:**
Don't use Background attachment fix for iOS.

So change your code in style.css from:

`#home-section { background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-attachment: fixed; min-height: 800px; }`

To:

`#home-section { background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; min-height: 800px; }`

**Alternate Solution:**
Find workarounds for making `background-attachment:fixed` work for different browsers. Here is something to get you started:

1. [Fixed background image with ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7)
2. [Fixed body background scrolls with the page on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045364/fixed-body-background-scrolls-with-the-page-on-ios7)